# Downvotes removed?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, down-votes

I'm confused.

I and another user downvoted and voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901203/how-to-login-user-to-my-website-using-twitter). Our downvotes are now gone; they just vanished.

Is this some new feature, or a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other downvoter removed their downvote after the post was edited. There is no downvote recorded from you, and the server logs only show your close vote request, no downvote.

Comment: I think I refreshed the page after I downvoted, and it was still there.